# Difference between findOneAndDelete() and findOneAndRemove()

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am not able to differentiate [findOneAndDelete()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndDelete) And [findOneAndRemove()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove) in the [mongoose documentaion](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query).

> **Query.prototype.findOneAndDelete()**
>
> This function differs slightly from Model.findOneAndRemove() in that
>   findOneAndRemove() becomes a MongoDB findAndModify() command, as
>   opposed to a findOneAndDelete() command. For most mongoose use cases,
>   this distinction is purely pedantic. **You should use
>   findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to.**

Comment: **"You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to"** reason like what ?

Comment: `findOneAndDelete()` executes the MongoDB [findOneAndDelete()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/) command and `findOneAndRemove()` executes the MongoDB [findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) command

Comment: Why **"findOneAndRemove() executes the MongoDB findAndModify()**" if it finally delete the document from collection?

Comment: And why they say **"You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to"**

Comment: It is not "**finally** delete the document from collection", it **deletes** the document from collection using `findAndModify` command with `remove: true` option straight away.

Comment: Then in what cases, I should use **"findOneAndDelete() "**

Comment: When findAndModify is not enough, e.g. you want to project returned documents, your filter doesn't include the shard key, etc You've got the links to the docs, take a look and compare which one meets your needs.

Comment: As @AlexBlex suggested, we can use one of the two based on the use case. Moreover `findOneAndDelete()` was introduced in recent version when compared to the other.

Comment: [Here ya go](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/e0c10b63889dcb8279a7034f754d264cd754a5fd/lib/query.js#L2922-L2926)

Answer (score 14):

**TLDR: You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to.**

---

Longer answer:

From the Mongoose documentation of findOneAndDelete:

> This function differs slightly from Model.findOneAndRemove() in that findOneAndRemove() becomes a MongoDB findAndModify() command, as opposed to a findOneAndDelete() command. For most mongoose use cases, this distinction is purely pedantic. You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to.

[Mongoose Docs findOneAndDelete](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete)

Comment: "You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to" reason like what ?

Answer (score 4):

In MongoDB native client (Mongoose is different)  passing `{ remove: true }` to `findAndModify` makes it remove the found document, it's behavior in this case would appear quite similar to `findOneAndDelete`.
However, there are some differences when using other options:

- [findAndModify](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) takes 5 parameters :`query`, `sort`, `doc` (the update object), `options` and a `callback`. [findOneAndDelete](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndDelete) only takes 3 (`filter` or query, `options` and a `callback`)
- `options` for `findAndModify` include `w`, `wtimeout` and `j` for write concerns, as:

  > “the level of acknowledgment requested from MongoDB for write operations to a standalone mongod or to replica sets or to sharded clusters.“ or simply guarantee levels available for reporting the success of a write operation.

  `options` for `findOneAndDelete` do not include write concerns configuration.
- `findAndModify` lets you return the new document and remove it at the same time.

Example:

```
// Simple findAndModify command returning the new document and
  // removing it at the same time
  collection.findAndModify({b:1}, [['b', 1]], {$set:{deleted: Date()}}, {remove:true}, calback)
```

Comment: I don't think any of these differences actually exist. (1) `findOneAndDelete` does take a sort option. (2) `findOneAndDelete` takes a `writeConcern` option, but [it's not documented](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-13857). (3) `findOneAndDelete` also returns the removed document.

Comment: Yes @ZachB findOneAndDelete() also returns the remove document(if any)

Answer (score 4):

Both of them are almost similar except **findOneAndRemove**  uses **findAndModify** with remove flag and time complexity will be a bit higher compare to **findOneAndDelete** because you are doing an update. Delete are always faster.

Comment: Both functions send the exact same command over the wire to MongoDB. There is no difference in time complexity.

Comment: They do not send the same command per mongoose documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete 


Also please check out MongoDB documentation: 

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/ 

Per my experience when you delete a large amount of data, you will see latency between these two commands because findAndModify return the data

Comment: see my answer. The driver converts the command. Both return the data.

Comment: "FindOneAndDelete() 

Finds a matching document, removes it, and passes the found document (if any) to the callback." According to the mongoose document findOneAndDelete also returns deleted documents if any.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here have a lot of wrong info. They are for all intents and purposes the same, and you should just use `findOneAndDelete()`.

Mongoose's `Model.findOneAndRemove(query)` becomes MongoDB's `findAndModify({query, remove: true})`.

Mongoose's `Model.findOneAndDelete()` becomes MongoDB's `findOneAndDelete()`. However, the MongoDB driver converts `findOneAndDelete(query, opts)` to `findAndModify({query, remove: true})` ([src](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/9587764ca77b60fbf464645159715428ff9fd217/src/operations/find_and_modify.ts#L160-L174)). Thus they do the exact same thing in the database.

Both take the same options.

Both return the deleted document.

Comment: so what's the point of having two functions if they both achieve the same purpose in the end?

Comment: Almost certainly legacy cruft.

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose findOneAndDelete works the same way as findOneAndRemove. They both look an object by its properties in JSON, then goes ahead to delete it and as well as return it object once after deletion. When you are using the native mongodb as your database findOneAndDelete might be useful to you, but in the case of mongoose it is deprecated I may advise you to use findOneAndDelete to perform your operation based on the latest mongoose and nodejs configuration as at this period. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6880

Comment: I got in from above github disscusson `DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.` Do you want to say, `findOneAndRemove`  uses `collection.remove` and  `findOneAndDelete`  uses (`collection.deleteOne` or `collection.deleteMany`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact difference (quoted from the mongoose docs in Model.findOneAndDelete() section):

> "This function differs slightly from Model.findOneAndRemove() in that
>   findOneAndRemove() becomes a MongoDB findAndModify() command, as
>   opposed to a findOneAndDelete() command. For most mongoose use cases,
>   this distinction is purely pedantic. You should use findOneAndDelete()
>   unless you have a good reason not to."

Here is the link to it:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete

Comment: For kind information findOneAndDelete() also return deleted document.

Answer (score 0):

findOneAndRemove returns the removed document so if you remove a document that you later decide should not be removed, you can insert it back into the db. Ensuring your logic is sound before removing the document would be preferred to checks afterward IMO.

findOneAndDelete has the sort parameter which can be used to influence which document is updated. It also has a TimeLimit parameter which can control within which operation has to complete

Comment: Both return the removed document. Both have a sort parameter. Both have time limits.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you use findOneAndDelete(). 
Mongoose provides both the features to handle data using the ORM and also features to write directly into the database, with findOneAndDelete() being one of the latter. Writing to database directly is more dangerous as you run the risk of not calling middleware or validators, potentially submitting partial or incomplete data to the database. Note that I said it's *more* dangerous, not that it's flat out dangerous, findOneAndDelete() just goes throughout the ORM adding safety.

Comment: Both go through Mongoose (the ORM) and have the same middleware caveats.